# Best way to make an iPhone application multi-lingual

Tags: iphone, xcode, multilingual

Can anyone tell me the best way to go about making an iPhone application support multiple languages?  I am going to put separate versions for each language in the App Store, but what is the best way to represent this in Xcode?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Putting a separate app in the store for each language is NOT the way to go. The iPhone SDK handles multiple languages with grace, and you only need to have a single app with all the various translations. The iPhone's locale setting will direct your app as to which language to use.

Answer (score 5):

A good place to start is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done iPhone dev yet, but "normal" Cocoa apps use ".lproj" strings files for different languages. See the docs about those, that should help. Good luck.