# iphone multilanguage support

Tags: iphone

hello all i am new to iphone development i want to use multilanguage application in  iphone please guide me how can i do it i dont know anything that how can i use multilanguage in iphone

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451776/best-way-to-make-an-iphone-application-multi-lingual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the keywords of **localization**, **internatialization**, iphone, ...

Here is a good **tutorial** http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone

and check out the **iPhone Dev Center** and its samples, like this one
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/InternationalMountains/Introduction/Intro.html

You'll find plenty of other tutorials around the net.