# How to integrate two languages (english or arabic) in one project in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios4

How to integrate two languages (english or arabic) in one poject in iphone sdk? Please Help me with code or anything else which is helpful to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451776/best-way-to-make-an-iphone-application-multi-lingual

Comment: You are going to use localization, and a lot of `NSLocalizedString(@"Hello World", @"hello message")` statements (well at least one for each string). You should see this guide on localization: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"ar" forKey:@"lang"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

just do that thing there is an Localized Clases it will be very easy for you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use localization for integrate two language in your app. for implementation you can refer this tutorial [Localization](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the testing codition and then the validating flag.

Set the language

```
 - (IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender{
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        if([sender tag] == 1){
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"en" forKey:@"lang"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            delegate.imgV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"t1.png"]];

        }else{
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"ar" forKey:@"lang"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            delegate.imgV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"at1.png"]];

        }
        [self presentModalViewController:delegate.nvCtr animated:YES];
    }
```

Checking your conditions

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lang"] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
//Do your code here
}
else if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lang"] isEqualToString:@"ar"]{
//Do your code here.
}
```

This code helping to solve your problem easily

@samuel.

Answer (score 0):

i did like this.

```
lang =  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Selected_Lang"]intValue];
if(lang == 0 )
{
    NSString *language = @"en";
    LocalizationSetLanguage(language);
}
else
{
    NSString *language = @"ar";
    LocalizationSetLanguage(language);
}
```